# Auto complete with multiple keywords

Tags: autocomplete

I want . Auto complete text box  with multiple keyword. it's from database. if I use jQuery and  do operation in client side mean. If the database size is huge, it leads to some issues. I need to know how this is done on the server side and get proper result.

I have already seen this topic but the operation is done on the client side. I need it from the database directly.

```
    <html>
 <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .srchHilite { background: yellow; }
    </style>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            NewAuto();
        });

        function NewAuto() {
            var availableTags = ["win the day", "win the heart of", "win the heart of someone"];
            alert(availableTags);  // alert = win the day,win the heart of,win the heart of someone
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: function(requestObj, responseFunc) {
                    var matchArry = availableTags.slice(); // Copy the array
                    var srchTerms = $.trim(requestObj.term).split(/\s+/);
                    // For each search term, remove non-matches.
                    $.each(srchTerms, function(J, term) {
                        var regX = new RegExp(term, "i");
                        matchArry = $.map(matchArry, function(item) {
                            return regX.test(item) ? item : null;
                        });
                    });
                    // Return the match results.
                    responseFunc(matchArry);
                },
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    // This function provides no hooks to the results list, so we have to trust the selector, for now.
                    var resultsList = $("ul.ui-autocomplete > li.ui-menu-item > a");
                    var srchTerm = $.trim($("#tags").val()).split(/\s+/).join('|');
                    // Loop through the results list and highlight the terms.
                    resultsList.each(function() {
                        var jThis = $(this);
                        var regX = new RegExp('(' + srchTerm + ')', "ig");
                        var oldTxt = jThis.text();
                        jThis.html(oldTxt.replace(regX, '<span class="srchHilite">$1</span>'));
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="tags">
            Multi-word search:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="tags" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need to load availableTags from database?

Comment: yes .I want to filer it in server side .

Answer (score 0):

take a look to Select2 it may help you.

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports
>   searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

[link](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have provided source as array. As you mentioned in comments, problem is how to get the data to source in jquery.

To make this work,
You need to do following

1. load jquery in header, which is you have already done.
2. Provid array,string or function for the  source tag. [See api for
   the source tag][1]

   ```
    [1]: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
   ```
3. In your serverside script, provid Jason encoded string.

If you check the API, you can see they have clear mentioned this.

Here is the jquery code

```
  $(function() {


    $( "#option_val" ).autocomplete({
     dataType: "json",
      source: 'search.php',
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Here is the php code, Sorry if you use differnt serverside script language.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","wordpress","password","wordpress");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from wp_users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

    $results[] = array('label' => $row['user_login']);
  }

echo json_encode($results);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. here my problem is. if the quering data is big how to filter it. if i return the full array mean either the client system is hang. my need is filter done in  server side.